# Setting up PhpStorm 10 for Remote Debugging

Tags: debugging, settings, phpstorm

I have just started using **PhpStorm** as my preferred PHP IDE tool. Also I have configured its interpreter  to use XAMPP PHP configuration (**php.ini**) which is 7.0 version. The help that I need is that my web application files are located on remote server and the application is **custom MVC** based. How can I setup my PhpStorm in order to debug PHP files? I tried to search on internet and YouTube but didn’t find the exact solution for this.

I have heard about **XDEBUG** but I am unable to find any source which can guide me step by step on how to configure it. And in case I configure it, my source files are on remote server which is more than 20 GB in size. So it is impossible to download all of them and setup them on localhost.

If anyone can help me in this so I will be highly grateful.

Comment: You still need local files for IDE to show them for you (otherwise how will you know at what line you are etc). In any case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Thanks for the comment LazyOne. The video inside the link teaches on how to debug a code. It doesn't tell on how to establish the debugger in PHPStorm.

Comment: Did you even noticed that except the video it also has tons of links for particular topics? Like [this one](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide) or [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) for example. Or even something simple like this: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=phpstorm+xdebug

Comment: Suggestion: if you do not know how xdebug works and how to configure it to work with IDE -- create simple project locally (one or two simple few-lines-only scripts is enough) and do local debug frist (you said that you have XAMPP installed, which you do not need for remote debug but can use for local testing). Once you learn how it works -- you can move on into remote debug.

Comment: A little help will be appreciated LazyOne from your side on make me learn how to do the remote XDEBUG setting because I can't download the all files in my local computer. I must need remote debugging in order to accomplish my assignments.